# How to find if exception was raised in previous task of airflow DAG?

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

Is there any elegant way of detecting if exception was raised in previous task(s) of the same dag?

I know I can set `TriggerRule =ALL_SUCCESS` so it will kick off only when all previous tasks `successfully` executed.

But in my case I need the trigger rule to be `ALL_DONE` and it will kick off on all valid states including `Failed once`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me your problem can be solved by adding an intermediate task as a downstream dependency of the first task with a `trigger_rule=all_failed`. Then set this intermediate task as an additional `upstream_dependency` of your next task as well.

This could look as follows:

```
task_1 = Operator()
task_1_on_fail = Operator(trigger_rule='all_failed')
task_1 >> task_1_on_fail

task_2 = Operator()
task_2_on_fail = Operator(trigger_rule='all_failed')
task_2 >> task_2_on_fail

collection_task = Operator(trigger_rule='all_done')
collection_task.set_upstream([task_1, task_1_on_fail, task_2, task_2_on_fail])
```

The `_on_fail` tasks should get marked as skipped in the case where the upstream task is successful which means the collection_task will run as normal. If the upstream task is unsuccessful, the `_on_fail` task will run first, after which the collection_task can proceed